# shp2pgsql available in postgis:13-3.1-alpine but no in postgis:13-3.1 docker image

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql, docker

From the [postgis/postgis:13-3.1-alpine](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/postgis/postgis/13-3.1-alpine/images/sha256-2d343af41add6928e8ffa8a8fefc4829a4fad3226df40b51d64eda8bdf54eef1?context=explore) docker image I can push 3 [shapefiles](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000280.shtml) into my database using `shp2pgsql` in an init script.

But from the [postgis/postgis:13-3.1](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/postgis/postgis/13-3.1/images/sha256-357d3e5396486e9c0253dd59adff854ea51fe7686c4b4c5097bcb013a941c138?context=explore) image I cannot:

```
(...)
db_1 | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: 19: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: shp2pgsql: not found
db_1 | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: 20: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: shp2pgsql: not found
db_1 | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: 21: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/11_init.sh: shp2pgsql: not found
```

Both [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) and [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) version are however the same.

If it was designed for a specific purpose, why and which one?

**Tip**: to the present day (20210114), as an inelegant workaround is to install... the `postgis` [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) package itself (yes, it sounds funky but it actually fixes the missing `shp2pgsql` binary)!

Comment: Fairly annoying once again. I think I had the same issue using the kartoza docker images, always had to install shp2pgsql again using apt..

Comment: That being said, kartoza has this nice feature that you can launch and init script once the container has been built https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis#environment-variables maybe something similar exists in the official image?

Comment: The official postgis image does have a `/docker-entrypoint.sh` script and a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder with a first init script `10_postgis.sh` to actually install all the necessary postgis stuff. So you can plug whatever other script in that folder, following that they will be run in alphabetical order at startup. This is what I actually did to insert data using `shp2pgsql` e.g. You can play with it using: `# docker run -it -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgis/postgis:13-3.1` and then connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I think I might have a more elegant solution to this.
You can use a multi stage docker build to install shp2pgsql and copy it to your final docker image. This would avoid to run `apt get` on your docker image.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM postgis/postgis:13-3.1 as builder
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y postgis
RUN which shp2pgsql

FROM postgis/postgis:13-3.1

COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/shp2pgsql /usr/bin/shp2pgsql

# check shp2pgsql is installed
RUN shp2pgsql
```